# Increase memory limit for background application

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7 gives you 6 MB of memory for a background application. How can I increase this limit?

I'm using WP 7.1.1 with the latest updates.

Comment: Too many question marks.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone has very strict rules about background agents. So, going past this limitation is not possible, unless you modify the registry after an interop-unlock.

Comment: That is a phone-specific solution. If you are developing an application, you cannot expect every user to do that. It also probably voids warranty.